# PHP CURL GET request returns 500 where bash curl succeeds

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm attempting to use PHP's CURL to make a GET request to a server and am having some difficulties doing so. When I make the request through PHP I am returned a 500 error from the external server. However, if I make the request using the bash curl, or visit the URL in a browser it succeeds.

I've stripped the PHP down to the bare essentials:

```
$url = 'http://example.com:8080/path/to/service?cmd=my_command&arg=example2.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

As stated this returns a 500 error from example.com. However, if I do the following:

```
[me@host ~] curl "http://example.com:8080/path/to/service?cmd=my_command&arg=example2.com"
```

I am returned the expected XML document.

What gives? It's got to be something with the encoding of the URL, as if I strip the `$url` var down to just `http://example.com:8080` the PHP CURL request now responds with 200. I've tried replacing the `&` with `%26` - that didn't work (nor would I expect it to, as `&` is valid in the URL there). I've tried doing what the answer for [php curl sending vars using GET wierd results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230774/php-curl-sending-vars-using-get-wierd-results) suggested, but that didn't help either.

What am I missing here? I'm sure that it's something absurdly simple, but it's escaping me.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've just attempted doing this in Python - just to see what happened - and it works fine there:

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen(theURL)
r.read()
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of curl_getinfo?

Comment: There's nothing particularly interesting there; http_code is 500, redirect_count is 0, content_type is text/html;charset=iso-8859-1, and the url is the string I passed in. The rest of the data there is pretty much just transfer speed info.

Comment: You're setting RETURNTRANSFER to 1 but not capturing the return value of `curl_exec`.  Either turn off RETURNTRANSFER or assign the return value of `curl_exec` to a variable and `print_r` that.

Comment: That doesn't affect the result of the HTTP request; it only comes in to place once the request has completed. In this case, the contents that would be stored there (or that would go to screen) is the HTML of the server's 500 page - which is not that helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the API I was accessing required a User-Agent for all requests, but did not provide any information to indicate such.

Is this a common thing? I can't find any other examples of anyone else doing this other than http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required

I was able to get things working just fine by adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent: Some-Agent/1.0");
```

Comment: I just ran into another API that required specific User-Agent headers.  It wouldn't work with non-browser user-agents even though it's a REST Web Service API.  Took me way too long to figure that out.