# cURL works great in terminal but dies with 500 error in script

Tags: php, curl, terminal

I have a problem similar to the one described here, though the suggested solution does not work for me:

[PHP CURL GET request returns 500 where bash curl succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717914/php-curl-get-request-returns-500-where-bash-curl-succeeds)

The suggested solution was:

"It turns out that the API I was accessing required a User-Agent for all requests, but did not provide any information to indicate such."

Which didn't work for me.

If I open a terminal window and do this:

curl "http://needi.local:8080/search/uber" -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnc'

I get all the results that I expect. It works great.

If I create this PHP file:

```
  <?php
  $command = "curl 'http://needi.local:8080/search/uber' -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnc'
  echo passthru($command);
```

This gets me:

```
  php -f tests/functional/curl_external_api_tests.php 
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  100   109  100   109    0     0   2893      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2945

  {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred"
  }
```

Adding the user agent does not fix the problem:

```
  $command = "curl 'http://needi.local:8080/search/uber' -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnc' --header 'User-Agent: PHP-test/1.0'
```

What else could the problem be?

[ UPDATE: ]

I am sorry if anyone thought this was a question about PHP. I should rephrase as "what might be different in a script, relative to what I do in the terminal?" I also tried to use bash and I got the same error. But the cURL works in the terminal. So what changes when I leave the terminal and instead use bash or PHP or anything else?

Comment: why are you not using the [php curl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: refer for [implementing your code using php curl library](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/701/how-to-use-curl-with-php)

Comment: You are not getting a 500 server error from the server directly. You are getting the expected JSON response, which happens to include an error from your usage of the API itself. Also, using `passthrough`  plus `curl` to call an HTTP API from PHP is almost always a really, really bad idea. Look at the answer @RohanKhude linked to.

Comment: I am sorry if anyone thought this was a question about PHP. I should rephrase as "what might be different in a script, relative to what I do in the terminal?" I also tried to use bash and I got the same error. But the cURL works in the terminal. So what changes when I leave the terminal and instead use bash or PHP or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your arguments to curl are getting truncated and so curl never passes the header. Do try using `escapeshellarg` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found a bug in the API app. So for anyone else who comes across this, I want to emphasize that my PHP worked great. I did get to the point where this worked:

```
<?php
  $command = "curl 'http://needi.local:8080/search/uber' -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnc'
  echo passthru($command);
```